# While loop only working for one condition

Tags: python, while-loop

Im trying to validate the user's input so he/she only types in 'all' or 'sel' (not case sensitive). Might just be some syntax mistake im making.

```
choice=input('Type "all" or "sel": ')
choice=choice.lower()

while choice!=('sel' or 'all'):
    choice=input('Invalid input. Try again: ')
    choice=choice.lower()
```

This only works if I type in 'sel', but not 'all'.

Comment: This is a consequence of two separate misunderstandings - I've given you links that address both of them

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: while choice.lower() not in ('sel', 'all'):

Comment: ('sel' or 'all') will always return 'sel' because 'sel' evaluates to true.  so your statement says "while choice != 'sel'"

Comment: I realized my mistakes thanks guys!